# The key selector type for the call to the 'GroupBy' method is not comparable in the underlying provider

Tags: c#, linq

I have this **LINQ** query:

```
var qty = db.WebOEOrdD.Sum(d => d.QTY);
var unitPrice = db.IcPricP.Select(p => decimal.Round(p.UNITPRICE, 2));

var query = from item in db.OrderFormDump
            join icp in db.IcPricP on item.ITEMNO.Replace("-", "") equals icp.ITEMNO
            join itemInfo in db.WebItemInfo on item.ITEMNO equals itemInfo.ITEMNO
            join weboeordh in db.WebOEOrdH on username equals weboeordh.USER
            join weboeordd in db.WebOEOrdD on new { itemno = item.ITEMNO.Replace("-", ""), orduniq = weboeordh.ORDUNIQ } equals new { itemno = weboeordd.ITEMNO, orduniq = weboeordd.ORDUNIQ }
            join weboeordsubmit in db.WebOEOrdSubmit on weboeordd.ORDUNIQ equals weboeordsubmit.ORDUNIQ where weboeordsubmit.ORDUNIQ != weboeordd.ORDUNIQ
            join webloginaccess in db.WebLoginAccess on username equals  webloginaccess.USER
            join arcus in db.Arcus on webloginaccess.CUSTID equals arcus.IDCUST
            where (item.ALLOWINBC == "Yes" && item.ALLOWINAB == "Yes")
            && icp.PRICELIST == arcus.PRICLIST
            && icp.CURRENCY == "CDN" && icp.DPRICETYPE == 1
            && (item.BASEDESCRIPTION.Contains(searchword) || item.DESCRIPTION.Contains(searchword) || item.CATEGORY.Contains(searchword) || item.FOODACCSPEC.Contains(searchword) || item.ITEMBRAND.Contains(searchword) || item.ITEMGROUP.Contains(searchword) || item.ITEMNO.Contains(searchword) || item.ITEMSUBTYPE.Contains(searchword) || item.ITEMTYPE.Contains(searchword) || itemInfo.INFO.Contains(searchword) || item.UPC.Contains(searchword) || item.UPC.Substring(2, 10).Contains(searchword))
            orderby item.BASEDESCRIPTION
            group item by new { item.ITEMNO, item.BASEDESCRIPTION, itemInfo.INFO, item.UPC, unitPrice, item.CASEQTY, qty } into items
            select new { items.Key.ITEMNO, items.Key.BASEDESCRIPTION, items.Key.INFO, items.Key.UPC, unitPrice, items.Key.CASEQTY, qty };
```

and I'm getting this error:

> The key selector type for the call to the 'GroupBy' method is not comparable in the underlying store provider.

I'm writing my LINQ query this way because I'm trying to convert it from this SQL query:

```
SELECT orderformdump.itemno,basedescription,info,upc,CAST(UNITPRICE AS DECIMAL(18,2)),caseqty, sum(qty) AS userquantity
FROM [DataWarehouse].[dbo].[ORDERFORMDUMP] 
LEFT JOIN PPPLTD.dbo.ICPRICP ON replace([DataWarehouse].[dbo].[ORDERFORMDUMP].[ITEMNO],'-','') = ICPRICP.ITEMNO
LEFT JOIN PPPLTD.dbo.WEBITEMINFO ON ORDERFORMDUMP.ITEMNO = WEBITEMINFO.ITEMNO
LEFT JOIN pppltd.dbo.weboeordh ON [user] = 'brian'
LEFT JOIN pppltd.dbo.weboeordd ON pppltd.dbo.WEBOEORDD.ITEMNO = REPLACE(datawarehouse.dbo.ORDERFORMDUMP.ITEMNO,'-','') and weboeordd.ORDUNIQ = weboeordh.orduniq
Left JOIN pppltd.dbo.weboeordsubmit ON weboeordsubmit.orduniq = weboeordd.ORDUNIQ and weboeordd.ORDUNIQ != weboeordsubmit.orduniq
LEFT JOIN PPPLTD.dbo.WEBLOGINACCESS ON WEBLOGINACCESS.[USER] = 'brian'
LEFT JOIN PPPLTD.dbo.ARCUS ON ARCUS.IDCUST = WEBLOGINACCESS.CUSTID
where (allowinbc = 'Yes' or allowinab = 'Yes') 
AND [PRICELIST] = ARCUS.PRICLIST 
and [CURRENCY] = 'CDN' and DPRICETYPE = 1
and (itemgroup like '%' + @search + '%' or itemtype like '%' + @search + '%' or itembrand like '%' + @search + '%' 
or subcat  like '%' + @search + '%' or orderformdump.description  like '%' + @search + '%' or basedescription like '%'+ @search + '%' 
or orderformdump.ITEMNO like '%'+@search+'%' or UPC like '%'+@search+'%' or (select top 1 1 from pppltd.dbo.ICITEMO where OPTFIELD like 'UPC%' and VALUE like '%'+@search+'%' 
and ITEMNO = DataWarehouse.dbo.ORDERFORMDUMP.itemno) is not null) 
group by ORDERFORMDUMP.ITEMNO,BASEDESCRIPTION,info,UPC,CAST(UNITPRICE AS DECIMAL(18,2)),caseqty
order by basedescription
```

and I'm not too sure how to convert such a long query like that.

**UPDATE**

I was getting this error because of my `unitPrice` and `qty` variables. After removing those, I get no more errors.

Comment: My guess is that it's because you're including `qty` in the grouping. Why are you doing that?

Comment: @JonSkeet I've updated my question to explain why.

Comment: Well that doesn't really explain what you expect it would do. Given that `qty` is a variable you declared earlier, how do you expect it to affect grouping? Have you tried *not* including it in your grouping? (I would suggest you try to reproduce this problem with a much simpler query, btw.)

Comment: The problem seems to be the `unitPrice` variable .. remove it from the group by and try again

Comment: @JonSkeet, @Slai Thank you. I've removed the `qty` and `unitPrice` variables and it doesn't give me the error anymore. Now I just have to figure out how to get the same results as my SQL query.

Comment: If one of these comments is thought to be the answer, it should be posted as an answer.